# React Router v4 how to specify allowed routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

These are routes allowed in my app:

```
/
/topic/development
/topic/database
/topic/security
/pages/:page (:page can only be a number)
```

I have a trouble displaying `Not Found` for the users when they visit something like:

```
/topic/whatever
```

Where can I specify which routes are allowed for the users?

Comment: you can manage it in the componentWillMount function in component loaded by destination route. You can tale a look to react-loadable to, it has nice features.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a `<Switch/>` have a component with no `path`.

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/will-match" component={WillMatch}/>
    ... More paths here
    <Route component={NoMatch}/>
  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mentioning "routes are allowed for the users?", which means there is some layer of authentication in your app.

Lets say in your initialState you have:

```
{
  user: undefined,
  logged: false
}
```

What you could do is decorate the route in order to check the state of this property, something like:

```
const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest);
  return (
    React.createElement(component, finalProps)
  );
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ user, component, redirectTo, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
      return user.logged ? (
        renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)
      ) : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: redirectTo,
            state: { from: routeProps.location }
          }} />
        );
    }} />
  );
};
```

You could now define routes and privateroutes, passing the necessary props:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Redirect to="/dashboard" />)} />
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={App} user={user} redirectTo="/login"/>
```

Then, the best solution to react to state changes would be implementing this in a redux way. Can ellaborate more if needed.